# Remove grub and restore WinXP bootpage

Tags: windows-xp, grub, bootloader

Is there any way to remove grub and restore WinXP's bootpage?

It is on netbook so I have no possibility to boot any CD, which didn't come with this netbook anyway.

BTW, does deleting the Ubuntu partition also delete grub2? Because I was thinking maybe I just could set the default OS to be XP, and then set the timeout to 0, and or hide grub on load.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used a little free utility called [MbrFix](http://www.sysint.no/nedlasting/mbrfix.htm) for this.

For Windows XP (assuming standard primary hdd install) the command you'll want is:

```
mbrfix /drive 0 fixmbr /yes
```

Comment: i didn't knew what that does, but anyway it killed all my partition. At start up now I get "invalid partition table"....

Comment: fixed it by fixing GRUB

Comment: Where do I run the command: 'mbrfix /drive 0 fixmbr /yes' ? On XP? On Ubuntu? I downloaded the program but don't know where to run this command. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should boot off the windows XP install disk and log into the recovery console by pressing R:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/recovery_run_console.mspx?mfr=true

Then you should use the fixmbr command.

www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true

I hope that helps. If you get stuck, try googling *grub xp fixmbr* or *grub xp fixboot*. I don't think you should need to use the fixboot command.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer tonight. I did restore windows MBR but what it does is to load the boot loader in the first sector of the only active partition on the Primary Master hard drive. What happened is that during the Ubuntu installation, the installer somehow changed the Windows partition (sda1) to be not active, only the Ubuntu partition (sda2) was active. Therefore, Windows MBR loads grub2 installed in the first sector of the Ubuntu partition instead of Windows. By making sda1 active again, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `mbr` package and running it to replace the grub code in the master boot record with as standard record will do it.  This will disable access to grub and leave you with only Windows.

Ubuntu now has a package to install onto a USB key.  This can be used to help recover a broken system, or for occational Linux usage.  You may want to build and test a key before replacing the mbr record.

Answer (score 0):

You could set grub to wait 0 seconds and automatically pick Windows, to correct this you'd need to edit the file from Windows. I'm not sure what you mean by bootpage, Windows does exactly the same thing after any boot loader.

Comment: I'm not sure what to call it either. But what I mean I don't want the grub, I intend to remove ubuntu from the laptop and only run winxp. So I don't want the grub page to load up